# Port 3000 is always being hogged by grafana-server

Tags: process, netstat, port

I need port 3000 free for my dev work. But it's being used by grafana-server, that I don't remember ever installing. We do use it within our company so perhaps at some point it has been added to system somehow.

[image: Example netstat output]

Anyway, so I use this command `sudo netstat -lepunt | grep 3000` to get the process that is on port 3000.

Then `sudo kill -9 [process number]` then I netstat again and it's there again but with a different process number.

I've also followed [this example](https://curiousviral.com/change-grafana-default-port/) to force the port number used to a different one but it still doesn't seem to fix my problem.

I've also tried to find every occurrence of grafana on my computer and delete them. Restarted services to make the system know that they no longer exist, but they still do. At the end of my wit and not sure what to do next. Any ideas? Any more information needed from myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to user [OweH_OweH](https://old.reddit.com/user/OweH_OweH) on reddit.

> systemd restarts it, because `grafana-server.service` has `Restart=on-failure` in it and by sending the process `SIGKILL` you trigger that failure state. If you just use the normal `kill PROCID_HERE` command it will terminate normally and not be restarted.

So I shouldn't have being adding the `-9` in my kill command.

Comment: I would recommend stopping and disabling the service instead of throwing kill signals at it.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: I would use `systemctl --now disable grafana-server`.

Answer (score 4):

I have been struggling to figure this out for mac. This page kept showing up. So, to help other mac users please use the following command
`brew services stop grafana`